# OpenALPR library issue with libpng and google play

Tags: android, google-play, libpng, openalpr

I've seen a few recent posts on Google Play rejecting apps with certain versions of libpng. This has tripped up with an update to my app, using the OpenALPR library, which does have an include libopencv_java.so, and have narrowed this down to be source containing libpng. 
My question is, can i compile a compatible version of libpng, and replace the .so in jniLibs? I am dubious of this solution, but I have read that opencv is dynamically linked, and will use a system default if available, but that seems to more apply to linux than android?
This is preventing me from publishing even though the app otherwise runs fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV [is now using a version](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/3rdparty/libpng) of libpng that's new enough to pass the security check that's preventing you from updating your app. I think your approach will work, and I'd first try building an up-to-date libopencv_java.so yourself and swapping that file into your app.

This is a reasonable approach because OpenALPR uses a standard, uncustomized version of this library, opting to put its custom image processing code in other, separate libraries.